# RadScheduler issues

Tags: .net, asp.net, telerik, telerik-scheduler

Q:
I'm using Telerik RadScheduler with data from two tables:

1. Course (**courseCode**,CourseTitle)
2. CourseTime(**id**,from,to,*courseCode*),the id is auto incremented

In the codebehind the Scheduler is bound to an ObjectDataSource:

```
    rs.DataSourceID = ObjectDataSource1.ID;
    rs.DataKeyField = "id";
    rs.DataStartField = "from";
    rs.DataEndField = "to";
    rs.DataSubjectField = "courseTitle";
    rs.DataBind();
```

1. When updating a course I want to update its name. For this I need to access the courseCode. The ObjectDataSource1 contains the courseCode, but I don't know how to bind it to the Scheduler control.
2. When inserting a new course I want to have a dropdownlist in the edit popup form, with a list of courses from the Course table.

I looked at the Telerik schedule samples and demos but i didn't understand the whole idea.
It would appreciate a simple code example showing how to bind more data to Scheduler appointments, and how to add new controls to the edit form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to template the Advanced(Edit)Form. It is rather easy to do so, since there are out of the box templates that can be modified to fit your requirements. I suggest that you take a look at the [following demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/advancedformtemplate/defaultcs.aspx) for details.